# Connecting MySQL DB table to my React.js application

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I have created a react application that should be connected to MySQL data base in order to save and keep user input when using my app, I have followed the bellow link to implement the connection, but it's not working!!

https://dev.to/saulojoab/how-to-get-data-from-an-mysql-database-in-react-native-53a4

any ideas guys?

I'm getting this error message on my div tools elements part : 
index.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 console. @ index.js:1

My application is not talking to mysql data base of which I already created, in my app the user should input name and email and this should be updated in to my database, but it is not..

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. We will need a little but more details on your question than "it's not working". Please add the error messages you are seeing in any log at you implementation. A clear error message will help us here to understand better why the error is happening and what may be wrong. Even based on the error you can also share some specific parts of the implementation that you think is related to it here in the question.

Comment: Sure, I'm getting this error message on my div tools elements part : index.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
beside, my application is never talks to mysql data base of which i already created it, in my app the user should input name and email and this should be updated in to my database, but it is not..

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60955222/edit) button and add those details on your question.